# What is getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I went through below React official site to understand about new life cycle method [`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

But I couldn’t understand the advantage of this method and when exactly we should use.

Below is the example from docs and it differentiates two methods.

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
// Are we adding new items to the list?
// Capture the scroll position so we can adjust scroll later.
if (prevProps.list.length < this.props.list.length) {
  const list = this.listRef.current;
  return list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop;
}
return null;
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // If we have a snapshot value, we've just added new items.
   // Adjust scroll so these new items don't push the old ones out of view.
   // (snapshot here is the value returned from getSnapshotBeforeUpdate)
   if (snapshot !== null) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
       list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The two paragraphs above the example you quoted explain the need for that:

> In the above example, componentWillUpdate is used to read the DOM
>   property. However with async rendering, there may be delays between
>   “render” phase lifecycles (like componentWillUpdate and render) and
>   “commit” phase lifecycles (like componentDidUpdate). If the user does
>   something like resize the window during this time, the scrollHeight
>   value read from componentWillUpdate will be stale.
>
> The solution to this problem is to use the new “commit” phase
>   lifecycle, getSnapshotBeforeUpdate. This method gets called
>   immediately before mutations are made (e.g. before the DOM is
>   updated). It can return a value for React to pass as a parameter to
>   componentDidUpdate, which gets called immediately after mutations.

In other words: React 16.6 introduced a new feature called ["Suspense"](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/01/sneak-peek-beyond-react-16.html). This feature enables async rendering - the rendering of a subtree of react components can be delayed (for example to wait for a network resource to load). It is also used internally by React to [favor important DOM updates over others](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-fall-in-love-with-react-fiber-90f2e1f68ded) to increase the perceived rendering performance. This can - as one would expect - cause substantial delays between the react-side virtual DOM rendering (which triggers `componentWillUpdate` and `render()`, but may contain some async component subtree which has to be awaited) and the actual reflection to the DOM (which triggers `componentDidUpdate`). In older react versions before Suspense these lifecycle hooks were always called with very little delay because the rendering was completely synchronous, which justified the pattern to gather DOM information in `componentWillUpdate` and use it in `componentDidUpdate`, which is no longer the case.

Answer (score 29):

The main difference is `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` runs **before** the update, `componentDidUpdate` runs **after**.

So if there is anything you need to save before it gets overwritten, that's what `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` is for. These are usually externally managed things (*uncontrolled* in React terms), such as the scrollPosition in your example, or when interoping with other libraries outside React (e.g. a jQuery plugin).

The main guideline is that if you are unsure, **you probably don't need it**. If you do, you will know it.

Answer (score 3):

I made a very simple project for you to understand when we should use getSnapshotBeforeUpdate life cycle method and I used getSnapshotBeforeUpdate to store user scroll position and used that in componentDidUpdate

github repository
https://github.com/mahdimehrabi/getSnapShot-sample

demo
https://mahdimehrabi.github.io/js/snapshot/

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually getSnapshotBeforeUpdate() runs ***after*** the update.

Consider this which kinda explains everything:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {x:1};
      console.log(1);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({x:2});
      console.log(3);
   }
   shouldComponentUpdate() {
      console.log(4);
      return true;
   }
   getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      console.log(5,prevState.x,this.state.x);
      return 999;
   }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
      console.log(6,snapshot);
   }
   componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log(7);
   }
   render() {
      console.log(2);
      return null;
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Demo />,
   document.querySelector('div')
);
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.querySelector('div'));
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
2
5 1 2
6 999
7
```

Comment: Here `beforeUpdate` mean DOM update. Most of time code in `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` looks like
```
if (prevState.msg !== this.state.msg) {
  const hello = this.helloRef.current;
  return hello.offsetLeft;
}
return null;
```